# ssh "tmux a || tmux" works sometimes?

Tags: ssh, tmux

This command works always (with sh or bash):

```
ssh -t HOST sh -c "tmux a 2>/dev/null || tmux"
```

These fail about half the time:

```
ssh -t HOST -- "tmux a 2>/dev/null || tmux"
ssh -t HOST "tmux a 2>/dev/null || tmux"
```

with an error from tmux, either `server exited unexpectedly` or `lost server`. (When testing there was no open tmux session so it always ran both commands.)

Why do they fail and only fail sometimes but not always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer:

> ```
> attach-session [-dErx] [-c working-directory] [-t target-session]
>               (alias: attach)
>         If no server is started, attach-session will attempt to start it; this will 
>         fail unless sessions are created in the configuration file.
> ```

- `tmux a` not only tries to attach but also starts a tmux server (which fails and starts to shut down).
- the `tmux` command tries to create a new session. Sometimes the server process from `tmux a` is still there, so it talks to that server
- finally the server process exits and `tmux` fails with the `server exited unexpectedly` message.